# Opening a textbox on selecting a radio button

Tags: html

I am fairly new to HTML, I want to open a text box when a particular radio button is selected

```
    <html>
    <table>

    <tr><INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="H"/> A </tr>

    <tr><INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="L"/> B </tr>

    <tr> <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="LL"/> C </tr>

    </table>

    </html>
```

I want to show

```
<tr> <TEXTAREA NAME="data" ROWS=10 COLS=50> </TEXTAREA> </tr>
```

when B is selected otherwise not show it. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to increase your accept rating if you want to get answers.

Comment: First I would get rid of tables! Then I would use a JavaScript library like jQuery, as you cannot hide any show fields dynamically using HTML you have to use a client or server side language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function show() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block'; }
        function hide() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none'; }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>        
      <form name="radios">
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="H" onclick="hide();"/>A 
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="L" onclick="show();"/>B 
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="LL" onclick="hide();"/>C
        <TEXTAREA id="area" style="display: none;" NAME="data" ROWS=10 COLS=50></TEXTAREA>   
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```